# Generating all combinations of elements from array in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to generate all the combinations possible by this rule:
take one element from every inner array and max combination is 4 element for combination
example:

i have array like this one:

```
[ [ '9', '8' ], [ '7', '10' ], [ 'Q', 'K' ], [ '7', 'K' ] ]
```

```
[
    ['9','7','Q','7'],
    ['9','10','K','7'],
    ['9','7','Q','7'],
]
```

and so on until all combinations has been generated

tried to use lodash but it didnt go well.

```
let data = [ [ '9', '8' ], [ '7', '10' ], [ 'Q', 'K' ], [ '7', 'K' ] ];
let combinations = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < data[1].length; j++) {
        for (let k = j + 1; k < data[2].length; k++) {
            for (let l = j + 1; l < data[3].length; l++) {
                combinations.push([data[0][i], data[1][j], data[2][k], data[3][l]]);
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(combinations);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use backtracking, where 'build' your solution, while iterating over all possible viable options. Think of it like a depth first search.

Procedure

1. Declare `output = []`
2. Declare `combo = []` <- current solution
3. Load Inner Array <-
4. For Each Value,

   1. Add the value to `combo`
   2. Check if there's a deeper level i.e. Another inner array

      1. If yes, repeat from step 2 on that level with the current combo as the initial combo
      2. If not, we've reached the end, so push `combo` to `output`
   3. Pop the value from `combo`

---

**Brief example with Input: `[[9,8],[7]]`**

```
Loaded: [9,8]
Combo: []
For each value [9,8]:
       Current Value: 9
       Combo: [9] // Push current value
       Check Next: [7] // Go deeper
            Loaded: [7]
            Combo: [9]
            For each value [7]:
               Current Value: 7
               Combo: [9,7] // Push 7 into combo
               Check Next: null // Cant go deeper
               Output: [[9,7]] // Push current combo
               Combo: [9] // Pop 7 out of combo
        Combo: [] // Pop 9 out of combo
        /* -------- Iterate -------- */
        Current Value: 8
        Combo: [8] // Push 8 into combo
        Check Next: [7] // Go deeper
            Loaded: [7]
            Combo: [8]
            For each value [7]:
               Current Value: 7
               Combo: [8,7] // Push 7 into combo
               Check Next: null // Cant go deeper
               Output: [[9,7],[8,7]] // Push current combo
               Combo: [8] // Pop 7 out of combo
         Combo: [] // Pop 8 out of combo
return Output = [[9,7],[8,7]]
```

```js
const input = [ [ '9', '8' ], [ '7', '10' ], [ 'Q', 'K' ], [ '7', 'K' ] ] 

function getCombos(array) {
  const output = []
  extend(array);
  return output;
  
  function extend(array, combo = []) {
    const current = array[0]
    for (let i = 0; i < current.length; i++){
      combo.push(current[i])
      if (array[1]) {
        extend(array.slice(1), combo)
      } else {
        output.push(combo.slice())
      }
      combo.pop();
    }
  }
}

console.log(getCombos(input))
```